# how to pass bash getopts argument to Python script with getopt

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a bash script which takes a getopt argument, builds a Python getopt option and tries to run a Python script passing the created getopt argument. However, this doesn't work.

My bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x 
set -e

while getopts "d:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        d) 
            echo $OPTARG
            MY_DATETIME_PARAM="--my-date ${OPTARG}"
            ;;
    esac
done

python my_python_script.py "${MY_DATETIME_PARAM}"
```

And my_python_script.py

```
import getopt
import sys

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "d:", ["my-date="])
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
    print(e)   
    sys.exit(1)    
    
for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt in ("-d", "--my-date"):
        print(arg)
```

And the result is

```
$ ./test.sh -d 2012-12-12
+ set -e
+ getopts d: o
+ case "${o}" in
+ echo 2012-12-12
2012-12-12
+ MY_DATETIME_PARAM='--my-date 2012-12-12'
+ getopts d: o
+ python my_python_script.py '--my-date 2012-12-12'
option --my-date 2012-12-12 not recognized
```

However, running the python script manually from cmd seems to work nice

```
$ python my_python_script.py --my-date 2012-12-12
2012-12-12
```

Comment: You're passing a single argument; need two - the option and the argument.

Comment: Don't use `getopt`. That exists mainly to help port non-Python code already using the `getopt` library to Python. Use `argparse` in the standard library, or one of several third-party options like `click` or `docopt`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are quoting `${MY_DATETIME_PARAM}` when calling python, which makes it a single string and a single argument instead of 2 separate arguments.

One way to solve this is to remove the quotes in the last line:

```
python my_python_script.py ${MY_DATETIME_PARAM}
```

That should work in this case, but is not very robust. A better way to do this is to store the arguments in an array, and then expand the elements of the array in the last line, like this:

```
declare -a parameters
while getopts "d:" o; do
  case "${o}" in
    d) 
      echo $OPTARG
      parameters+=( "--my-date" "${OPTARG}" )
            ;;
  esac
done

python my_python_script.py "${parameters[@]}"
```

You can then easily add parameters by adding to the array.

It is important to note that the array expansion in the last line *is* quoted. This ensures that spaces in the array elements are handled correctly. The shell interprets the quotation marks as meaning: "Quote each element of the array", rather than "Quote all elements after expansion". For example:

```
> parameters=( "Hello" "Bon jour" "Auf wiedersehen, Pet" )

> echo ${parameters[@]}
Hello Bon jour Auf wiedersehen, Pet

> echo "${parameters[@]}"
"Hello" "Bon jour" "Auf wiedersehen, Pet"
```

Even though the array only contains 3 strings, the first echo results in 6 separate strings containing no spaces. The second echo gives the correct result. 3 strings, some containing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You need three changes :

```
declare -a MY_DATETIME_PARAM
...
              MY_DATETIME_PARAM=(--my-date "${OPTARG}")
...
python my_python_script.py "${MY_DATETIME_PARAM[@]}"
```